# Mirroring 2 Host with their own local storage

Tags: vmware-vsphere, network-attached-storage, vmware-vcenter, failovercluster, infrastructure

I'm trying to decide between 2 infrastructures.

**1.** 2 Servers host that point to a NAS

**2.** 2 Servers that mirror each other with their own local storage.

**Infrastructure Requirements:** 50 TB of storage, Active Directory, SQL Server, Remote Access, able to supply up to 50 users.

**Will buy 2 of these:** [HP 850519-S01 | neweggbusiness.com](https://www.neweggbusiness.com/product/product.aspx?item=9b-2ns-0006-0k1a5)

From my research, the 2nd option provides better HA since the 2 Host don't depend on anything but themselves. I'm planning to use VMWare on the host. I'm assuming VMWare can handle this? Meaning can it basically Mirror everything on Host 1 to Host 2?(including storage). So basically all the VM machines, all its files, databases, configs, etc are on both local storages.

If so, is there a guide on how to do this?(I will be learning how to use VMWare). Is it a feature that all VMWare versions include?

If you believe option 2 isn't a good option, may I hear your reasons on why? I was planning on option 1 with my earlier question. [Creating a new Infrastructure for my company using Windows Server and FreeNas | Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/907044/creating-a-new-infrastructure-for-my-company-using-windows-server-and-freenas/907047?noredirect=1#comment1173672_907047)

But now I'm thinking option 2 is better for us. I appreciate any help/advice from all.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [StarWind VSAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/) 2-nodes hyperconverged solution on VMware [here](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-hyperconverged-2-node-scenario-with-vmware-vsphere-6-5).

It gives a possibility to mirror storage between the hosts and present it as HA datastore to the cluster. Virtual Machines can be deployed then on a top of HA datastore.

Additionally, they have a ready for Production hardware solution - [StarWind HyperConverged Appliance](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-hyperconverged-appliance).

Comment: I actually was looking into this. Appears that the free version can be used in production.

Comment: If you’ll get more nodes you can look at Ceph as well.

Answer (score -3):

There is no vmware product that "mirrors" VMs from one host to another. Typically one either uses vSphere Replication which is asynchronous and has a minimum RPO of 5 minutes or a NAS/block device that provides asynchronous and/or synchronous replication (e.g. EMC VNX devices).

Comment: I looked more into vSphere replication and it appears to be what I was needing. Which of the 2 options would you prefer that I mentioned above?

Comment: "There is no vmware product that "mirrors" VMs from one host to another. " (c) ... There is! It's called Fault Tolerance and it's with VMware vSphere for years. https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.availability.doc_41/c_plan_understand_ft.html